# Python - import cv2 after installation vidgear

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi-zero

I installed RasPiOS Bullseye OS in my Raspberry Pi zero, with Python 3.9.2.
I installed opencv with
`sudo apt install python3-opencv -y`
I test `import cv2` and it works. Then I installed vidgear with `pip3 install vidgear` .
I test `import cv2` and not works:

> > > RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xf but this version of numpy is 0xd
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Numpy version is 1.19.5. The same version that was there before installing vidgear.

I tried `pip3 uninstall numpy` and `pip3 install numpy==1.19.5` , but don't work, same error.

Can you help me, please?
thank you,

Comment: sudo pip3 install numpy --upgrade

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried"Installing collected packages: numpy
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.5
    Not uninstalling numpy at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
    Can't uninstall 'numpy'. No files were found to uninstall.
Successfully installed numpy-1.23.3" but not work, same error.

Comment: Btw, Python come with numpy. I ma not familiar vidgear